# How to not display certain options in a dropdown in django?

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application in django. I have a model called plan. Here is the code:

```
class StripeObject(models.Model):

    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Plan(StripeObject):
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    interval_count = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    statement_descriptor = models.TextField(blank=True)
    trial_period_days = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({}{})".format(self.name, CURRENCY_SYMBOLS.get(self.currency, ""), self.amount)
```

I want that when I display the `Plan` in a dropdown where users can select a plan to subscribe to, it should only show options where type = 'binary'.

Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Is this dropdown in an AdminForm, Changelist Filter or in a View? If in a view what kind of view? Function or class based? Should this filtering work everywhere, or only on the Admin Site or only in one place?

Comment: Why don't you just provide your template with prefiltered list of objects of type = `'binary'`? It would be the simplest solution.

Comment: What do you currently have in your template/view? In the simplest case, you could use a `filter` on `type='binary'`